# How can i show a ProgressBar when mediaPlayer is prepairing to play

Tags: android, progress-bar, media-player

This is the code in my main Activity:

```java
private void initControls()
 {
  streamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stream);
  streamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
        loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    Toast
    .makeText(
      MyActivity.this,
       "The following stream is about to start" + station,   
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    player.playAudioFile(urlstring2);
    streamButton.setEnabled(false);
    notificate();
   }
  });
 }
```

And here is the code in witch i start the mediaplayer itself:

```java
public class player extends MyMainActivity{

static MediaPlayer player;
private static final String TAG = player.class.getSimpleName();



public static void playAudioFile(String urlstring2) {


    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(urlstring2);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player.prepareAsync();
        //player.start();

    } catch (Throwable thr) {
        Log.e(TAG, "could not play audio", thr);
        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
            loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

public static void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        // Player-Ressourcen freigeben
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

}

What I want to do is to show the progressBar (the cicling one) when the user presses the "play" Button, and I need it to disapear when the mediaplayer starts to play.
atm I just get the circle to show after the player has startet to play and never disapear ...

**Edit:** I got it to work.
I did initiate the player like this: player.prepare(); insteas of player.prepareAsync();
So the progressbar was shown for a view milliseconds.

Comment: please edit your question with where you start the progress bar and all. BCoz I am not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: http://mobilesdevelopment.com/how-to-show-progressbar-while-loading-a-video-in-android-videoview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to finally mark this Question as solved, so I copied what I edited into my question previously.

> I got it to work. I did initiate the player like this:
>   player.prepare(); insteas of player.prepareAsync(); So the progressbar
>   was shown for a view milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

Start the Progress Bar in the button click here like this,

```
 streamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
   public void onClick(View view)
   { 
   ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;   
 progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Playing..."); 
    Toast
    .makeText(
      MyActivity.this,
       "The following stream is about to start" + station,   
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    player.playAudioFile(urlstring2);
    streamButton.setEnabled(false);
    notificate();
   }
  });
```

And you  have to override the media player's on Prepared listener, so that you can stop the progress bar within it like this,

```
Player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.cancel();

            }
        });
```

By this you can achieve to show Progress until your Mediaplayer starts to play the file.

Comment: I tried to to initiate the ProgressBar like you suggested. First i make a Variable `public ProgressBar loading;`an then i´ve set the visibility at the same point of code you put it `public void onClick(View view)
    {

  loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
  loading.setVisibility(1);
  
     Toast
     .makeText( ` but still i get the ProgressBar AFTER the mediaplayer is playing. Where is this going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add the code to hide your ProgressBar after this line:

```
player.start();
```

And also in your catch block. That should make it go away once the player is either playing, or failing to play.

If you add the code that you are using to show the ProgressBar now I can help you with how to hide it also.